# Why arent npm version settings working?

Tags: npm

I've run the commmand

`npm version 1.4.24`

Which has correctly updated my `package.json` file to

`"version": "1.4.24",`

But when I run `npm install` it would appear that npm is still working off of version

```
2 info using npm@2.1.8
3 info using node@v0.10.33
```

I'm not overly familiar with npm but from reading docs, I would expect that once I've run the proper command and updated package.json, I should be able to `npm install` using the prior npm version.

Thoughts on what direction to go with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `version` attribute in package.json refers to your [project's versions](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#version), not npm's. 
You can use npm to (globally) **update** itself to the latest version, or **install** a specific version.

- **update**

  `npm update -g npm`
- **install**

  `npm install -g npm@1.4.24`